# Java HashMap memory, to reduce it

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm using a HashMap in java and I have noted that it is consume too much memory, but I have the necessity to search the elements to quickly possible.

Is there something in order to reduce the memory of the hashMap if I know before how much element I will put inside?

Because I know how much information I will to store it, but I don't know it.

Because my problem is to read a file and in this file there are some information dived in two set and I have to connect these information in the same struct.

I know that the HashMap in order to work well wastes more than 25% of the memory that it has get.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How have you noted that it consumes too much memory?

Comment: Because when I launch the program I have put some `System.out.println`that give me some information like this: `Long usedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();`

Comment: That output is essentially meaningless. Unless you've properly profiled your application, there's no reason to assume that (1) there's a problem or (2) that it has the slightest to do with your maps.

Comment: You talk about two sets of information being loaded into memory and you use the word "struct" (presumably that would be a Java class). *This* information consumes memory, and likely far more memory than the internal mechanics of the `HashMap`. You're just measuring the total of the memory used by `HashMap` *and* your data, so why are you assuming that it's all consumed by the `HashMap`. Don't you think your *data* consumes memory too?

Comment: I have tested the program without the large data: `HashMap <int ,int>` for instance but I always the same problem about the memory.

Comment: A `HashMap <int ,int>` is not possible in Java since `int` is a primitive type. You can only have a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`. If you have a huge amount of numbers, than it's conceivable that boxing them inside `java.lang.Integer` objects is costing too much memory, but putting them in a HashMap in itself is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: *"... but putting them in a HashMap in itself is unlikely to be the issue."* -  Each `HashMap` entry consists of 2 header words + 3 references + 1 `int`.  That does not include the "share" of the main hash array, or the space that the key and value objects occupy.  In fact, a HashMap entry is bigger that (say) an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
new HashMap<>(capacity);
```

Comment: That will not make it use *less* memory, you just pre-allocate it to a (presumably) larger capacity, so it doesn't have to auto-grow there.

Comment: @Andreas: OP knows exact number of elements that will be stored, so there is no reason to allocate more than this.